# Android - default value in editText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my app I have an edit user details page and I want to display the current name, email address etc in the corresponding editText fields and then the user can just erase that and enter a new one if they want.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help

Comment: This site is for you http://developer.android.com/index.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`EditText.setText(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to set the current text of an EditText field.

Example:

```
yourEditText.setText(currentUserName);
```

Comment: This crashes my app. :(

Answer (score 44):

There is the `hint` feature? You can use the `setHint()` to set it, or set it in XML (though you probably don't want that, because the XML doesn't 'know' the name/adress of your user :)  )

Comment: Thanks for the hint ;) This is something to make the hint a little bit different from the regular text: 
  title.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<small style=\"text-color: gray;\"><i>" + DEFAULT_TITLE + "</i></small>"));

Comment: to set hint in java -> `inputPhoneNumber.setHint(R.string.examplePhoneNumber);`  (thank you Nanne)

Answer (score 29):

From the xml:

```
  android:text="yourtext"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with TextView (i tried with android api 4.0).

Answer (score 14):

You can use *text* property in your *xml* file for particular Edittext fields.
For example :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET_User"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="yourusername"/>
```

like this all Edittext fields contains text whatever u want,if  user wants to  change particular Edittext field he remove older text and enter his new text.

In **Another way** just you get the particular **Edittext field id** in activity class and set text to that one.

Another way = programmatically

**Example:**

```
EditText username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_User);

username.setText("jack");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in this way

```
private EditText nameEdit;
private EditText emailEdit;
private String nameDefaultValue = "Your Name";
private String emailDefaultValue = "abc@xyz.com";
```

and inside onCreate method

```
nameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    nameEdit.setText(nameDefaultValue); 
    nameEdit.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (nameEdit.getText().toString().equals(nameDefaultValue)){
                nameEdit.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    nameEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {               
            if(!hasFocus && TextUtils.isEmpty(nameEdit.getText().toString())){
                nameEdit.setText(nameDefaultValue);
            } else if (hasFocus && nameEdit.getText().toString().equals(nameDefaultValue)){
                nameEdit.setText("");
            }
        }
    });     

    emailEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    emailEdit.setText(emailDefaultValue);   
    emailEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {               
            if(!hasFocus && TextUtils.isEmpty(emailEdit.getText().toString())){
                emailEdit.setText(emailDefaultValue);
            } else if (hasFocus && emailEdit.getText().toString().equals(emailDefaultValue)){
                emailEdit.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think you do not have to add the ontouchlistener, it can work with just the setonfocuschangelistener for both fields.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to load the user details somehow

Then you need to find your EditText if you don't have it-

`EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittext);`

after you've found your EditText, call

```
et.setText(theUserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        EditText et_city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_city);
        // Set the default text of second EditText widget
        et_city.setText("USA");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android android:hint for set default value or android:text

Answer (score 0):

We wish there is a default value attribute in each view of android views or group view in future versions of SDK. but to overcome that, simply before submission, check if the view is empty equal true, then assign a default value

example:

```
   /* add 0 as default numeric value to a price field when skipped by a user,
                    in order to avoid parsing error of empty or improper format value. */
                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(edPrice.getText()).toString().trim().isEmpty())
                    edPrice.setText("0");
```