# Eclipse: Creating a search box with the attributes Enter city, zipcode

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello I have little to no experience using eclipse but I was wondering how I could create a search field where the user can enter a value. But I want the search field to say enter city or zipcode until the user inputs something. On html it's very simple, but I was wondering if anyone knew on Eclipse. I googled somethings but didn't really see too much kept linking me to SWT widget but it doesn't seem right. Thank you in advance

Comment: " but I was wondering if anyone knew on Eclipse" - you mean 'on Android' right?

Comment: Could be a function in Eclipse (like a drag on drop item) but yes Android

Comment: Are you asking how to have default value in Android edittext ? Did you check this link?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349061/android-default-value-in-edittext

Comment: Use Android `EditText` for your requirement.And Eclipse does have drag and drop functionality too.Read some basic tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

This is the xml file.

```
    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    <!-- List View -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This above code creates a search box where user can search city or zipcode.

In the java file do something like this.

```
EditText inputSearch;
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);        
 inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                AndroidListViewActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Create a filter and show the item in the list of xml above.