# how to take default value of an edittext as 0?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple android app in which 2 text fields are there.input range is 0 to 15. If the number is in range than addition is performed.

i have implemented input varification so now if the edit text is empty it shows empty field warning. but calculation is not done. what i want is if the field is empty is should show the error but also do the addition by take default value as 0.

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText check,check2;
private TextView textView;
private TextInputLayout checkLay,checkLay2;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeWidgets();

    initializeListeners();
}

private void initializeWidgets(){

    check=findViewById(R.id.check);
    check2=findViewById(R.id.check2);
    checkLay2=findViewById(R.id.checkLay2);
    checkLay=findViewById(R.id.checkLay);
    button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);

}

private void initializeListeners() {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signUp();
        }
    });
}
private void signUp(){

    boolean isVailed=true;

    int a1,a2;

    String one=check.getText().toString();
    String two=check2.getText().toString();

    if(one.isEmpty()){

        checkLay.setError("YOu need to enter something");
        isVailed=false;
    }
    else {
        if (one.length() > 0)
        {

            a1=Integer.parseInt(one);
            if(a1> 15){
                checkLay.setError("quiz marks must be less than 15");
                isVailed=false;

            }


            else  if(a1 <=15)
            {

                checkLay.setErrorEnabled(false);
                isVailed=true;
            }

        }

    }
    if(two.isEmpty()){

        checkLay2.setError("You need to enter something");
        isVailed=false;
    }
    else{
        if (two.length() > 0)
        {

            a2=Integer.parseInt(two);
            if(a2 > 15)
            { checkLay2.setError("quiz marks must be less than 15");
                isVailed=false;
            }

            else
            if(a2 <=15)
            {
                checkLay2.setErrorEnabled(false);
                isVailed=true;
            }
        }

        if(isVailed)
        {
            int total;
            a1=Integer.parseInt(one);
            a2=Integer.parseInt(two);
            total=a1+a2;
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it differently but for your specific question

```
if(one.isEmpty()){

    checkLay.setError("YOu need to enter something");
    isVailed=false;
}
```

Change to

```
if(one.isEmpty()){

    checkLay.setError("YOu need to enter something");
    a1=0;
}
```

Same for the two.isEmpty()

Comment: Even after initialising it is not taking the value as 0

Comment: That's because in your if(isVailed) you are reassigning them again. You need to remove a1=Integer.parseInt(one); and a2=Integer.parseInt(two); as others pointed it out.

Comment: I made it working... rearranged the loops and after checking if the string is empty it assigns value to 0...i will update the post with working code... thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a field is empty you set `isVailed` to `false` and thus say not to add the numbers. Instead you want to set the corresponding number to zero and let `isVailed` be `true`:

```
if(one.isEmpty()){

    checkLay.setError("YOu need to enter something");
    a1 = 0;
}
```

and

```
if(two.isEmpty()){

    checkLay2.setError("You need to enter something");
    a2 = 0;
}
```

Also throw off the lines

```
    a1=Integer.parseInt(one);
    a2=Integer.parseInt(two);
```

You already convert inputs to a1 and a2 earlier.

---

A piece of advice: you have doubled code. It's better to use functions for such pieces of codes.

Comment: I am very new in this....only have experience in beginner level C language.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your initializeWidgets function

```
yourEditText.setText(0);
```

follow link for more help: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349061/android-default-value-in-edittext)

Comment: This kind of worked not exactly how i want but close. I put this line in where @Pixels told to put a1=0 now it shows error and put 0 in text field if its empty if i click button than it adds the zeros

Answer (score 0):

You can create a convenience method to get value from your `edittext`. The following code will return `0` if `edittext` is empty else the value from the `edittext`

```
private int getIntFromEditText(EditText editText) {
  return editText.getText().length()>0 ? Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()):0;
}
```

Call it by passing `EditText` as a parameter, e-g

```
a1=getIntFromEditText(check)
```